# Multiple conditions in the not in function PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to check whether the user has watched a video. I have two tables- one populated with the video id and user id of watched videos. The other has the videos.

```
SELECT * 
FROM videos 
WHERE Channel LIKE '%$finalmood%' 
AND WHERE NOT IN(select * from userviews 
    where userviews.videoid = videos.id 
    where userviews.userid = $tempuser
```

I think I may be using the notin function improperly. How would I go about positioning multiple conditions on the notin function?

Thanks in advance-

Comment: just remove second where in (Where not in) and second one after (videos.id) change it to and

Comment: I want it to select a row that hasn't been watched yet- so NOT IN is a key function. At least, I believe

Comment: don't use `select *` as you're not taking advantage of any indices that may exist and are probably getting more data than you'll actually use. Also, try to rework your query to exist without `not in` as it is horribly slow.

Comment: Are there any ways around Not in @hd1

Comment: Not seeing your database, I have no idea.

Answer (score 4):

You could this with a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM videos 
LEFT JOIN userviews ON userviews.videoid = videos.id AND userviews.userid = $tempuser
WHERE Channel LIKE '%$finalmood%' AND userviews.videoid IS NULL
```

Btw, make sure that you sanitize `$tempuser`.

Comment: I second this approach as sub selects are more resource intensive (i.e. slower).

Comment: why 'AND userviews.videoid IS NULL'?

Comment: @Akam It selects the rows that are not matched in the `userviews1` table.

Comment: Would this be an effective way if my userviews table was potentially thousands and thousands of rows? I populate userviews based on if the user watched a video.

Comment: @user2040490 If `userviews.videoid` is indexed properly it should work okay; the determining factor here is really the number of entries in `videos` though.

Comment: thousands, hopefully @Jack